# intent not working when swiching from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made a simple android program with two activities,in that 1st activity contains an edittext and a button,and second activity contain a textview.Now when the button in 1st activity pressed the text from Edittext should go to 2nd activity's textView.I have tried code as below,but it's not working:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myweb";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act2.class);
            String s= ed.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", s);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Act2.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
                Intent i =getIntent();
                String msg = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            tv.setText(msg);

            setContentView(tv);





            }
        });
    }
}
```

please help me.thank you

Comment: received any error???????????

Comment: when i run it...in emulator 1st activity shown,but when i put some text and click the button .it shows "unfortunately app running stopped"

Comment: In second activity you should use bundle to get data from first activity

Comment: Post the logcat o/p of crash

Comment: @user2334694 Check my edited answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293455/intent-not-working-when-swiching-from-one-activity-to-another/16293578#16293578

Comment: bundle?how can i use it?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html . A simple example for use of Bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this:

In MainActivity.java:

declare Button b and EditText ed as a class field (i.e. keep it outside onCreate())

```
class MainActivity.java
{
Button b;
EditText ed;
...

onCreate() {
...
        b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_msg);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
            String s= ed.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", s);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
...
```

In Act2.java:

```
    ...
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String msg = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
tv.setText(msg);
     Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });
    ...
```

Comment: i have edited as per u have told...but same problem remains..:(

Comment: @user2334694 I have doubt that you have not any  button button1 in act2.xml. You should post logcat. Else no one will be able to help properly. You can't expect us to solve error without knowing what error you are getting :)

Comment: Sir...thank you...i was made that i have put a button click on it and no such btton is there.............thank you very much....for solution..have a nyc day.:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16293578/1777090 already mentioned your solution. @user2334694 Glad it helped

Comment: Heyy, don't call me sir. Please. But feel happy to help people here with whatever i know.

Comment: m sorry sir...m new to stack overflow...so...i'll take care next time..than you so much for helping me...

Comment: kindly accept the answer of @AReader. Think he's dying without the acceptance for his answer. I don't run for reputation, just enjoy helping here. Thats it.

Comment: Aw man... I have requested @user2334694 to accept your answer. What else shall i do for you now ?

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

So, in MainActivity

```
i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, s);
startActivity(i);
```

(OR)

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

also,

```
i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", s);
```

Comment: see the difference carefully. i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE"). So in 2nd activity, you should use message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

Comment: @ling.s You have been warned in the past about asking people to accept/vote for your answers. *Please stop doing this*.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
String msg = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

to

```
String msg = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

`MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE` would mean a static variable of `MainActivity.java` class. Hope you get the difference. You need the variable `EXTRA_MESSAGE` which you had put in `intent i`

Edit: For your crash, we need a logcat o/p and activity, manifest code. But possible reasons:

1. Activity `Act2.java` is not declared in `manifest` file.
2. You said you have only a textview in second activity. But you are trying to get `button1` from `act2.xml`. So you are getting Force close.

Change `Act2.java` 's `onCreate()` as

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act2);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
    Intent i =getIntent();
    String msg = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
    tv.setText(msg);
}
```

You don't need to call `setContentView(tv);` as it is already there in act2.xml and you are using `setContentView(R.layout.act2);`

Hope your problem gets solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Use this code 

    **MainActivity.java**

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

}

**activity_main.xml**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

**SecondActivity.java**

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

     Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView textView = new TextView(SecondActivity.this);
                textView.setText(message);

                setContentView(textView);

            }
        });
    }

}


**second.xml** 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />



</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tester"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tester.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i have edited it..but same eroor that "unfortunately youa ap has stopped"..:(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Act2.class);
```

Comment: You should declare all your activities' names in manifest xml too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

So, in MainActivity

```
i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, s);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of the EXTRA_MESSAGE variable in MainActivity.java is different then the key value that you are putting message in to intent.

MainActivity.java:

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myweb";

i.put("EXTRA_MESSAGE",s);
```

Act2.java: (you are accessing by extra_message variable which is not correct)

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String text = i.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); //WHICH IS DIFFER FROM THE KEY VALUE
```

So key value should be the same at the time of setting and getting the value. here while setting the value key is "EXTRA_MESSAGE" and while getting "com.example.myweb" so you will get null pointer exception.

SOLUTION:

just change the line in Act2.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String text = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

Also check your menifest file for the activities declaration.

Hope it may help you.

Comment: so i have to initialise it to "null"..?

Comment: Sir...i have edited...but...!and also have cheked in manifest..i think some other problem..!

Answer (score 0):

please review and change your code its works

```
  package com.example.activityact;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   Button b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act2.class);
       String s= ed.getText().toString();

       i.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", s);
           startActivity(i);

       }
   });

  }

 }
```

**Act2.java**

```
package com.example.activityact;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act2);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Intent i =getIntent();
    // String msg = i.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    //String receiver = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
    tv.setText(message);

}

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you remember to correctly define your second activity in the manifest XML?

Check out this great guide for anything else you might have missed: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: i have gone thru it..but can't find